# illegal hardware instruction git init - Apple M1

Tags: git, apple-m1

I recently switched to the new Macbook Air M1 (macOS Big Sur) and after successfully migrate my data from my old computer (Macbook Air on macOS Sierra), my git command is broken. When I try to initialize git with `git init` I got illegal `hardware instruction  git init`. Any idea what this could be? I've tried to install the latest XCode release but it didn't solve it.

Update: I actually solved this by re-installing git with the Binary installer: https://git-scm.com/download/mac

Comment: How did you install git? My git is located at /usr/bin/git so you might have installed a intel-binary but haven't installed rosetta 2. You can try installing git using homebrew. git --version
git version 2.24.3 (Apple Git-128)

Comment: Thanks for answering, I solved this issue with the update of my post.